# Change nav when scrolled over class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, scroll

I've got a snippet of code below that is designed to change the colour of my fixed nav to match the div the user is scrolling past.

The problem I'm having is that as there are multiple instances of the same element throughout the page they all try to remove the background class when the user is not over itself.

How can I get this to trigger only when the use scrolls off the element and not when ever it is outside of the region?

I am new to jQuery so any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $(".banner").each(function(){
    var windowScroll  = $(window).scrollTop(),
        bannerTop     = $(this).offset().top,
        bannerHeight  = $(this).outerHeight(),
        bannerbottom  = (bannerTop + bannerHeight),
        bgColor       = $(this).attr("primary-colour");

    // When the window scrolls over the banner then change the nav colour
    if ((windowScroll >= bannerTop) && (windowScroll <= bannerbottom)) {
      $(".body-header").css("background", bgColor);
    }
    else {
      $(".body-header").css("background", "");
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x789qh7m/1/

Comment: Show us the html code or make an JSFiddle please.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki here you go my man:
https://jsfiddle.net/x789qh7m/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will work only when header is over last banner.It is not working correctly, because when scrolling, you're iterating over **all** banners. So even if first banner will set color, `.each` will iterate until the last one (orange) and it will reset it. 

If I understood you correctly, this is the your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/x789qh7m/3/ - I just put body of `else` before iteration over banners.
The algorithm is simple - on scroll set no background by default and if there is some banner below- then change background to the same color.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".body-header").css("background", "");
    $(".body-header").removeClass("invert");
    $(".banner").each(function () {
        var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            bannerTop = $(this).offset().top,
            bannerHeight = $(this).outerHeight(),
            bannerbottom = (bannerTop + bannerHeight),
            bgColor = $(this).attr("primary-colour");

        if ((windowScroll >= bannerTop) && (windowScroll <= bannerbottom)) {
            $(".body-header").css("background", bgColor);
            $(".body-header").addClass("invert");
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much @alynioke, I knew it would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just return false to jump out of the `each` loop. Cant iterate over all since your else overrides the value of the background css property:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".banner").each(function() {
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      bannerTop = $(this).offset().top,
      bannerHeight = $(this).outerHeight(),
      bannerbottom = (bannerTop + bannerHeight),
      bgColor = $(this).attr("data-colour");

    // When the window scrolls over the banner then change the nav colour
    if ((windowScroll >= bannerTop) && (windowScroll <= bannerbottom)) {
      $(".body-header").css("background", bgColor);
      $(".body-header").addClass("invert");
      return false;
    } else {
      $(".body-header").css("background", "");
      $(".body-header").removeClass("invert");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.body-header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.banner {
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
.banner:nth-child(5) {
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="body-header"></nav>
<section class="banner" data-colour="rgb(52, 49, 57)">
  <div style="background: rgb(52, 49, 57); width: 100%; height: 200px"></div>
</section>
<section class="banner" data-colour="rgb(234, 104, 52)">
  <div style="background: rgb(234, 104, 52); height: 200px"></div>
</section>
<section class="banner" data-colour="rgb(14, 104, 52)">
  <div style="background: rgb(14, 104, 52); height: 200px"></div>
</section>
```